# MySQL Inserts getting weird errors on Linux after testing fine on Windows

Tags: mysql, linux

So I did all of these originally in PHPMyAdmin on Windows and they all worked fine, but now that I've moved the .sql file over to Linux to use with PHPMyAdmin there I'm get 1459 errors (all stemming from the same issue, I believe)

Anyway, here's the code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person
(
person_id INT(9) NOT NULL,
person_first_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
person_last_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
person_phone_number INT(11) NOT NULL,
person_birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
person_is_employee BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
person_is_patient BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);

INSERT INTO person
(person_id, person_first_name, person_last_name, person_phone_number, person_birth_date, person_is_employee, person_is_patient) 
VALUES
(1, 'Dan', 'Letersky', 381214214, STR_TO_DATE('1/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), FALSE, TRUE),
(2, 'Dave', 'Altvater', 541907901, STR_TO_DATE('2/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), FALSE, FALSE),
(3, 'Doug', 'Aiken', 661324324, STR_TO_DATE('3/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, TRUE),
(4, 'Dean', 'Marra', 701542542, STR_TO_DATE('4/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE),
(5, 'Alice', 'Altvater', 541907901, STR_TO_DATE('5/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE),
(6, 'Andy', 'Letersky', 681214214, STR_TO_DATE('6/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE),
(7, 'Andrew', 'Aiken', 661324324, STR_TO_DATE('7/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE),
(21, 'sDan', 'sLetersky', 2381214214, STR_TO_DATE('8/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), FALSE, TRUE),
(22, 'sDave', 'sAltvater', 2541907901, STR_TO_DATE('9/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), FALSE, FALSE),
(23, 'sDoug', 'sAiken', 2661324324, STR_TO_DATE('10/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, TRUE),
(24, 'sDean', 'sMarra', 2701542542, STR_TO_DATE('11/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE),
```

I'm getting these errors:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if this works .... it ran for me without the errors that you mentioned

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
>   person_id INT(9) NOT NULL, person_first_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>   person_last_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL, person_phone_number INT(11) NOT
>   NULL, person_birth_date DATE NOT NULL, person_is_employee BOOLEAN NOT
>   NULL, person_is_patient BOOLEAN NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (person_id) );
>
> INSERT INTO person (person_id, person_first_name, person_last_name,
>   person_phone_number, person_birth_date, person_is_employee,
>   person_is_patient)  VALUES (1, 'Dan', 'Letersky', 381214214,
>   STR_TO_DATE('1/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), FALSE, TRUE), (2, 'Dave',
>   'Altvater', 541907901, STR_TO_DATE('2/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), FALSE,
>   FALSE), (3, 'Doug', 'Aiken', 661324324, STR_TO_DATE('3/9/1988',
>   '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, TRUE), (4, 'Dean', 'Marra', 701542542,
>   STR_TO_DATE('4/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE), (5, 'Alice',
>   'Altvater', 541907901, STR_TO_DATE('5/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE,
>   FALSE), (6, 'Andy', 'Letersky', 681214214, STR_TO_DATE('6/9/1988',
>   '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE), (7, 'Andrew', 'Aiken', 661324324,
>   STR_TO_DATE('7/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE), (21, 'sDan',
>   'sLetersky', 2381214214, STR_TO_DATE('8/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), FALSE,
>   TRUE), (22, 'sDave', 'sAltvater', 2541907901, STR_TO_DATE('9/9/1988',
>   '%d/%m/%Y'), FALSE, FALSE), (23, 'sDoug', 'sAiken', 2661324324,
>   STR_TO_DATE('10/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, TRUE), (24, 'sDean',
>   'sMarra', 2701542542, STR_TO_DATE('11/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE,
>   FALSE)

`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! Unfortunately it didn't work. Can you tell me what the change you made is?

Answer (score 0):

From error it seems, this could be Quote issue. Windows and Linux manages quotes differently. Please check sql file quotes and correcte them, it should work.

Change person_phone_number field to VARCHAR(11). Phone no value is going out of range.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person
(
person_id INT(9) NOT NULL,
person_first_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
person_last_name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
person_phone_number VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
person_birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
person_is_employee BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
person_is_patient BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);

INSERT INTO person
(person_id, person_first_name, person_last_name, person_phone_number, person_birth_date, person_is_employee, person_is_patient) 
VALUES
(1, 'Dan', 'Letersky', 381214214, STR_TO_DATE('1,9,1988', '%d,%m,%Y'), FALSE, TRUE),
(2, 'Dave', 'Altvater', 541907901, STR_TO_DATE('2,9,1988', '%d,%m,%Y'), FALSE, FALSE),
(3, 'Doug', 'Aiken', 661324324, STR_TO_DATE('3/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, TRUE),
(4, 'Dean', 'Marra', 701542542, STR_TO_DATE('4/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE),
(5, 'Alice', 'Altvater', 541907901, STR_TO_DATE('5/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE),
(6, 'Andy', 'Letersky', 681214214, STR_TO_DATE('6/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE),
(7, 'Andrew', 'Aiken', 661324324, STR_TO_DATE('7/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE),
(21, 'sDan', 'sLetersky', 2381214214, STR_TO_DATE('8/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), FALSE, TRUE),
(22, 'sDave', 'sAltvater', 2541907901, STR_TO_DATE('9/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), FALSE, FALSE),
(23, 'sDoug', 'sAiken', 2661324324, STR_TO_DATE('10/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, TRUE),
(24, 'sDean', 'sMarra', 2701542542, STR_TO_DATE('11/9/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: I've tried using backticks, retyping quotes within the Linux VM, etc. Could you maybe elaborate further?

Comment: got this.. "person_phone_number" field value for rows 21,22,23,24 are out of range. INT(11) is not able to occupy given numbers. Better to take phone no field as varchar(11). In any case, generally you dont need arithmetic operation on phone numbers. This will solve your issue.

Comment: That did not work, I really don't think it has anything to do with the INT datatype, as I've used that for phone numbers in the past for previous SQL with no issues.

Comment: Can you please give what errors you got while executing above mentioned query. because, the same query runs successfully in phpmyadmin, I tested.

Comment: Another thing regarding INT datatype is, its value depends upon whether operating system is 32-bit or 64-bit. It can be possible that windows and linux systems you are using may be of different bits os. And even it is better to use Varchar in case of phone numbers, because phone no should be allowed chars as well, because following are the valid phone nos. **+1-541-754-3010 , (541) 754-3010** etc..